# Could not lock IndexWriter isLocked [false]

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I try to create an index in a couple of seconds and i got this:

```
[2014-06-02 14:10:14,414][WARN ][index.engine.internal    ] [shardicaprio] [myindex][0] Could not lock IndexWriter isLocked [false]
```

And here is full stack trace:

```
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/shardicaprio/nodes/0/indices/myindex/0/index/write.lock
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:702)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.createWriter(InternalEngine.java:1388)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.start(InternalEngine.java:256)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.postRecovery(InternalIndexShard.java:684)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:158)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:189)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-06-02 14:10:14,533][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [shardicaprio] [myindex][0] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [myindex][0] failed recovery
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:248)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.engine.EngineCreationFailureException: [myindex][0] failed to create engine
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.start(InternalEngine.java:258)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.postRecovery(InternalIndexShard.java:684)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:158)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:189)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/shardicaprio/nodes/0/indices/myindex/0/index/write.lock
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:702)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.createWriter(InternalEngine.java:1388)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.start(InternalEngine.java:256)
        ... 6 more
[2014-06-02 14:10:14,536][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [shardicaprio] [myindex][0] sending failed shard for [myindex][0], node[kHOedr2wQpa3DSZj81ep_A], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [29Uf2hH4S2-FJf1LnNrM0A], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[myindex][0] failed recovery]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[[myindex][0] failed to create engine]; nested: LockObtainFailedException[Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/shardicaprio/nodes/0/indices/myindex/0/index/write.lock]; ]]
[2014-06-02 14:10:14,536][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [shardicaprio] [myindex][0] received shard failed for [myindex][0], node[kHOedr2wQpa3DSZj81ep_A], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [29Uf2hH4S2-FJf1LnNrM0A], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[myindex][0] failed recovery]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[[myindex][0] failed to create engine]; nested: LockObtainFailedException[Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/shardicaprio/nodes/0/indices/myindex/0/index/write.lock]; ]]
```

I have no memory overloading, my heapsize is fine, but CPU. CPU gets overload even more than 100% of usage. I tried to recover index, delete index, recreate index but it tells the same thing every time. I could not figure it out that what causes this.

Any idea?

Comment: Does the path `/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/shardicaprio/nodes/0/indices/myindex/0/index` look like the right place to you?  And does elasticsearch have permission to write to it?

Comment: Yes. Path is correct and ES has a full permission on it. It keeps creating indices and they're fine. Just a single "index" that I defined above causes this exception.

Comment: I think there is two instance running in your server.. Can you check those.  Ps-ef | grep elastic

Comment: Nope @BlackPOP, certainly I run only one instance one node single shard.

Comment: It is a centos 32bit oracle jvm installed already.

Answer (score 0):

I did not face the problem again since I have added this line into elasticsearch.

```
index.store.fs.lock: none
```

I think this is caused by file system locking by elasticsearch. If I say Elasticsearch instance not to lock store file system it does not occur.

Comment: I don't understand... How will elasticsearch write to files in the FS if it can't obtain a FS lock?